# Sorting Algorithms in a single Java Application using FileReader

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, filereader

I am trying to use several sorting methods for a text file. I can get the `filereader` to work however it doesn't sort the `arrays`.  When I did it manually without `filereader` it did work. 
Here I use simple bubble sort as it had worked manually but now wont.

This is my Code:

```
public class BubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File f=new File("filename.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
    String s = br.readLine();
    while (s != null)
    {
        alist.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        s = br.readLine();
    }

    int[] iArray = new int[alist.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++)
            iArray[i] = (int) alist.get(i);

    System.out.println(alist + " ");
    bubbleSort(iArray);
    printarray(iArray);
    fr.close();
    }//end loop

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] alist) {

    int outer, inner;
        for (outer = alist.length - 1; outer > 0; outer--) { // counting down
            for (inner = 0; inner < outer; inner++) { // bubbling up
                if (alist[inner] > alist[inner + 1]) { // if out of order...
                    int temp = alist[inner]; // ...then swap
                    alist[inner] = alist[inner + 1];
                    alist[inner + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printarray (int []alist){

        for (int i = 0; i < alist.length;i++){
            System.out.println("" + alist);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your sort routine

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first of all, you should add the generic declaration to your arraylist so you can let  java decide how to unbox the value.

```
ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
```

should be

```
ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

-

```
iArray[i] = (int) alist.get(i);
```

will be

```
iArray[i] = alist.get(i);
```

Anyway your code works, but you should be way simpler about outputting these arrays (dont let javas verbosity get to your logic!)

```
    System.out.println(alist.toString());

    bubbleSort(iArray);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iArray));
```

your program outputs for me:

```
[144, 3, 1, 5, 4, 9, 9, 13]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 9, 13, 144]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your code is compiling and you just have omitted the imports.

Your code seems to work, the problem is while printing the resulting array, you are printing the entire array each time on the loop:

```
public static void printarray (int []alist){
 for (int i = 0; i < alist.length;i++){
     System.out.println("" + alist); //Printing entire array
 }
}
```

It should be printing each value:

```
public static void printarray (int []alist){
 for (int i = 0; i < alist.length;i++){
     System.out.println("" + alist[i]); //Index added
 }
}
```

Besides that I have several suggestions:

1. Avoid throwing an exception from your main method, and instead do a try/catch block to handle an error.
2. The code is using doble space in memory as you are creating an ArrayList and a primtive array, to make this better just use one structure.
3. Also, consider using generics for type safe Collections.

Regards.